# terraform cloud - no provider exists with the given name

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I have the "k8s" provider added to my Git repo as per [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/run/install-software.html#custom-and-community-providers)

```
<plan_dir>/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-k8s_v0.7.7
```

However on Terraform Cloud it still fails with **no provider exists with the given name**
What could be causing this?

Comment: You should add the provider to the custom provider registry in your Terraform Cloud and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Don't think that's an option in Terraform Cloud?? The link I have to the docs above. Adding it to the Git repo is the only option for adding custom providers in TFC

Comment: Ok right, that was misleading in the TF Cloud interface. Another option would be requesting the author publish the provider to the public registry and you can retrieve it from there.

Comment: Distribution of third-party providers via a registry (either the public one or a private one) is a forthcoming Terraform v0.13 feature. Terraform v0.13.0 is in beta testing at the time I'm writing this, so it's not yet available in Terraform Cloud, but this is indeed likely to become the best approach once the final release is out. Terraform Cloud releases are on a separate schedule, so I'm not sure if the Terraform Cloud private registry will have provider support before Terraform v0.13.0 final is release, but public registry currently has a beta version of community provider publishing.